# Can't see lookup fields in Workbench

Tags: data

I created myObject with lookup fields and deployed it to production org. I can see the lookup fields when I'm browsing it in Salesforce. But I can't see the fields when I'm running queries in production Workbench. How can I add them or make them visible so that I can run SOQL queries on them in Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I had to change field-level security permissions.